# How do I remove the <br> in billing address and display address and city text before the value ( woocommerce thankyou page )?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Do you know how to remove the br tag in billing address ( thankyou page ) ?
I try to find it in "abstract-wc-order.php", but nothing show up.
When the user place the order, it will redirect them to the thankyou page with their billing address. When I inspect the html code, I see the street address and then 
 city. I don't want the br tag there. Also how do I add the "address" and "city" text before the "Winter street" in php.
For example, Address: Winter street
City: Philadelphia

```
  <p>Winter street<br>Philadelphia</p>
```

Comment: Post your theme code for that page

Comment: Okay, I put the code here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/xuhb3eup/

Comment: this not the full code can you please post full code or your site address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Advised to change the core files but here's where it is

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details-customer.php
```

Modify the code as under:

```
<address>
<?php 
//echo ( $address = $order->get_formatted_billing_address() ) ? $address : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
Name: <?php echo $order->billing_first_name; ?>
<?php echo $order->billing_last_name; ?>
<br>Address:
<?php echo $order->billing_address_1; ?>
<?php echo $order->billing_address_2; ?>
<br>City:
<?php echo $order->billing_city; ?>
<br>State:
<?php echo $order->billing_state; ?>
<br>PostCode:
<?php echo $order->billing_postcode; ?>
<br>Country:
<?php echo $order->billing_country; ?>
</address>
```

Comment: I also provided the file location and the file name

Answer (score 0):

You can user very simple php function str_replace for removing br, p tags
like this

```
$clean_data=str_replace(array('<br>','<br />','<p>','</p>'),'',$your_input_data);
```

Comment: You need to put this code where you want to append data in url so the data be available in thank you page